# Oracle SQL how to find a employee whose department's code is null

Tags: sql, subquery, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

```
SELECT ID user_id, NAME user_name, SALARY user_salary, DEPARTMENT user_dept_code
FROM EMPTABLE
WHERE (DEPARTMENT, SALARY) IN (
    SELECT DEPARTMENT, MAX(SALARY)
    FROM EMPTABLE
    GROUP BY DEPARTMENT
)
ORDER BY DEPARTMENT;
```

The result of the code above doesn't contain any employee whose DEPARTMENT is null.
How can I make them in the result too?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the employee(s) with the greatest salary in each department - presumably, you want a group for employees that have no department as well.

I would recommend window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select e.*,
        rank() over(partition by deptcode order by sal desc) rn
    from emp e
) e
where rn = 1
order by deptcode
```

Answer (score 0):

For oracle, you may try to use NVL2 :

```
SELECT EMPID, EMPNAME, DEPTCODE, SAL
FROM EMP
WHERE (NVL2(DEPTCODE, DEPTCODE, ''), SAL) IN (
    SELECT NVL2(DEPTCODE, DEPTCODE, ''), MAX(SAL)
    FROM EMP
    GROUP BY DEPTCODE
)
ORDER BY DEPTCODE;
```